# javac command prompt parameters

Tags: java, command-prompt

I installed java on my machine and I wanted to compile this group of source code. But when I opened up the command prompt and typed in javac, the command prompt said it was an unknown parameter. The same thing happened when I wanted to build something with ant (I had the build.xml if you are wondering) and the same thing happened. How can I set the javac and ant command to be used in any directory?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you typed and what messages came back on the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you have to be sure you installed **JDK** and not only **JRE**

Secondly it depends on your operating system:

- windows: you have to reach environment variables by using *My Computer* (manage->advanced->something here)
- linux/osx: you have to export variables with *export* command or by using a **.profile** file in user directory

Then you need to set two things:

- adding /jdk_1.6.../bin/ to your **PATH** variable
- setting **JAVA_HOME** to your root of java installation ( /java_1.6..../ ) (maybe this is not required by java itself but many frameworks use it)

One note: on **OSX**, and maybe **Linux** too you have to split paths in **PATH** variable with double colon ':' instead that semicolon ';'

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory the executable is in to the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are using Windows. Right click `My Computer` and click `Manage`. Then, in the `Advanced` tab, select `Environment Variables`. In the new window, under `System variables`, find `Path` and append the full path to the binaries (`javac` and `ant`) at the end, separated by semicolons.